# Several questions about plist in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I implemented the plist in my iOS game following [***this***](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5) tutorial:

Now I have several questions about plist file in iphone.

1. My plist file is fine, but my plist file in the project folder is not changed when write data to the plist file. The tutorial said " Find the Data.plist file in ~/Documents and open it in a text editor", but I can't find ~/documents. So where it is? (the changed plist file)
2. In my plist file, I wrote highscore into it. When I published my game, and update my game  later, the plist file is it will be reset to default? In other words it will be overwrite?

Comment: When you say you can't find "~/Documents" do you mean programmatically or using the Finder?

Comment: Actually,I don't understand the what is ~/Documents. My .plist file is in my project folder, but I can't find the plist file that was changed by my code.

Comment: '~', when used in Unix file system paths, has a special meaning. It refers to your user directory on your system's storage. It expands to a path like "Users/username/Documents". For example, for you it might be "Users/ycz/Documents" and for me it is "Users/ThomasW/Documents". In the finder it is the "Documents" folder which shows up on the left hand side of Finder windows in the default configuration.

Comment: Thanks thomasW! I know the '~' means, but I can't find the plist file in any "~/Documents" folder, In my opinion, the tutorial is means the plist file in project folder, but in that folder, my .plist file is not changed when I write data to it, and I can read the changed data from the .plist file even I closed my project. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question.

1-> To view your .plist file in XCode , you will have to **create** and **add** that in your project through the `xCode.

2- From Apple documentation .

> Because the property-list file is in
>   the Resources folder, it will be
>   written to the application’s main
>   bundle when you build the project.

So it will be overwritten every time when you build your project. therefore when user update the game it will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks jhaliya, I already create and add the plist file into my project, and it worked fine, I can read the data from the plist file after closed the project, Can I find the that "edited" .plist file? under your answer, when I build my project the plist file will written to the application's main bundle, it's means need some other tools or method to view the "edited" plist file which in the main bundle?

Comment: Yes,I create the .plist file by myself. these has two property, by default they were "0" string. When I run my project and write the plist, the .plist file in my xcode is not changed. but I can read the changed value through the read plist API.

Comment: ###Thank you guys, you're so kind. I find the changed .plist file in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ under this article ! [link](http://richard.giliam.net/?p=13)